# VSCode Launch.json -- Use globally installed jest

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, jestjs, vscode-debugger

I have a current workspace structure as follows

[image]

Each of the folders (auth, client, tickets, common) have their own node_modules folder (I'm writing microservices). The .vscode folder has a launch.json file.

My tickets folder is as follows

[image]

I want to be able to add the following script to launch.json

```
 {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest Current File",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
      "args": [
        "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "--config",
        "${workspaceRoot}/jest.config.js"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "disableOptimisticBPs": true
    },
```

I.e, I want to be able to use the debugger on the current open test file.

But, as you can see, we have

> ```
>      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
> ```

The root workspacefolder has no node_modules. Jest is installed separately in each microservice.

I got do a hack like ${workspaceFolder}/tickets/node_modules/.bin/jest. But that seems messy -- What if I was running tests in the auth folder? It'll work but ... just messy.

Alternatively, I can point to my global installation of jest... but i can't seem to find the correct syntax to include it (I know that my global npm installed packages are here: /usr/local/lib/node_modules)....

Do you guys have any solutions? I'd appreciate the help/advice, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't globally installed Jest be available as `jest` without any path? That's the purpose of having globally installed NPM packages.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and install jest as a globally available package

```
$ npm install jest --global

$ jest --version
26.6.3

$ whereis jest
/usr/local/bin/jest
```

Update your launch.json

```
"program": "/usr/local/bin/jest",
```